# don't know how to use bg-gradient, i tried looking on some tutorials, but it doesn't show up on my project

Tags: css, frontend, vue-component, css-gradients

I am new to css and vue and anything about the front-end.

I am working on a project and I try to use gradient but it doesn't t show up on my project.

The gradient isn't working somehow ..

[image]

[image]

I posted two ss to see.

Comment: what browser and what version are you using

Comment: Opera gx, latest version

Comment: Try it on google chrome latest version and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

What you put inside an HTML tag is considered as text,
I'm not familiar with vue but looks to me like you are trying to add a class to an HTML tag, and put it as text instead of a class.

So just move .bg-gradient-primary inside the class (also remove the dot in front).

Edit : Didn't see you include the class name, so most likely your DIV is height 0 and width 0, try giving it width and height in CSS

Edit V2: If it's not this then make sure you added the exact same class name and included the library you are trying to use